# SQLite Error: Couldn't read row 0, col -1 from CursorWindow

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I try to retrieve the some data from my SQLite db in android but I get some error.

First of all Here is a snippet of my DB code:

```
private static final String TABLE_NAME_UrlCache = "UrlCache";
private static final String COLUMN_NAME_UrlCache_ID = "id";
private static final String COLUMN_NAME_UrlCache_TIME = "time";
private static final String COLUMN_NAME_UrlCache_DATE = "date";
private static final String COLUMN_NAME_UrlCache_CLIENTIP = "clientip";
private static final String COLUMN_NAME_UrlCache_CLIENTMAC = "clientmac";
private static final String COLUMN_NAME_UrlCache_REQUESTEDURL = "requestedurl";
private static final String COLUMN_NAME_UrlCache_FILENAME = "filename";
private static final String CREATE_TABLE_UrlCache = "CREATE TABLE " +TABLE_NAME_UrlCache+ " (" + COLUMN_NAME_UrlCache_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " + COLUMN_NAME_UrlCache_TIME +" text, " + COLUMN_NAME_UrlCache_DATE + " text, "+ COLUMN_NAME_UrlCache_CLIENTIP + " text, "+ COLUMN_NAME_UrlCache_CLIENTMAC + " text, "+ COLUMN_NAME_UrlCache_REQUESTEDURL +" text, "+COLUMN_NAME_UrlCache_FILENAME+" text "+");";


 public boolean addRequestedURL(String time,String date,String client_ip,String client_mac,String url,String file_name)
{
    Log.d("Client mac db", client_mac);

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put(this.COLUMN_NAME_UrlCache_TIME, time);
    contentValues.put(this.COLUMN_NAME_UrlCache_DATE, date);
    contentValues.put(this.COLUMN_NAME_UrlCache_CLIENTIP, client_ip);
    contentValues.put(this.COLUMN_NAME_UrlCache_CLIENTMAC, client_mac);
    contentValues.put(this.COLUMN_NAME_UrlCache_REQUESTEDURL, url);
    contentValues.put(this.COLUMN_NAME_UrlCache_FILENAME, file_name);
    db.insert(TABLE_NAME_UrlCache, null, contentValues);

    return true;
}


public boolean FileFromUrlAlreadyRequested(String url)
    {

        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

        try
        {
            Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("select requestedurl from "+ TABLE_NAME_UrlCache, null);


            try {

                if (cursor.moveToFirst())
                {
                    do
                    {

                        String retrieved_url = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DBManager.COLUMN_NAME_UrlCache_REQUESTEDURL));
                        String retrieved_id = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DBManager.COLUMN_NAME_UrlCache_CLIENTMAC));

                        if (retrieved_url.equals(url))
                        {
                            this.setID(retrieved_id);
                            return true;
                        }

                    } while (cursor.moveToNext());
                }

            }
            finally
            {
                try
                {
                    cursor.close();
                }
                catch (Exception ignore) {}
            }

        }
        finally
        {
            try
            {
                db.close();
            } catch (Exception ignore) {}
        }

        return false;

    }
```

And here is the Error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Couldn't read row 0, col -1 from CursorWindow.  Make sure the Cursor is initialized correctly before accessing data from it.
                                                                      at android.database.CursorWindow.nativeGetString(Native Method)
                                                                      at android.database.CursorWindow.getString(CursorWindow.java:438)
                                                                      at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.getString(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:51)
                                                                      at com.android.python27.DBManager.FileFromUrlAlreadyRequested(DBManager.java:427)
                                                                      at com.android.python27.Download$GetRequestedURLAsyncTask.onPostExecute(Download.java:267)
                                                                      at com.android.python27.Download$GetRequestedURLAsyncTask.onPostExecute(Download.java:193)
                                                                      at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:631)
                                                                      at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:177)
                                                                      at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:644)
                                                                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
                                                                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4867)
                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1007)
                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:774)
                                                                      at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

It crushed when I try to retrieve the mac address here:

```
String retrieved_id = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DBManager.COLUMN_NAME_UrlCache_CLIENTMAC));
```

I checked with Lod.d to see if I pass the variable with success and as I can see the new record was created with success.

Any advice would be helpful and deeply appreciated.

Comment: You're only selecting one column, but you're trying to find two. Fix that first.

Comment: Not an answer, just a suggestion though: don't hardcode column names inside of your sql queries. Use `String` constants you created instead. This way you won't put yourself in troubles when you decide to change some column names in the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You try to read `DBManager.COLUMN_NAME_UrlCache_CLIENTMAC` column but it's not in your projection list.

Change your SQL query to select both `DBManager.COLUMN_NAME_UrlCache_CLIENTMAC` and `DBManager.COLUMN_NAME_UrlCache_REQUESTEDURL`.

Answer (score 0):

Your variables are declared as 'private' that means it only can be accessed within the class, try changing it to 'public' instead.